# Mask data in a specific postion and specific record type

Tags: string, bash, replace, mask

Updated:

I have a file which is quite big. I need to mask all characters in specific postions and from a specific record type. I have searched all over the place but cannot find a solution of this quite simple task. Here is an example

File name: 
hello.txt

File:

0120140206INPUT FILE
1032682842 MR SIMPSON
20231458 742 Evergreen Terrace
3034560817 GREEN
1032682842 MR GRIFFIN
20231458 Spooner Street
3034560817 RED
3001

What I would like to do is to mask position 12-16 of all lines starting with 10. Like this:

0120140206INPUT FILE
1032682842 XXXXXMPSON
20231458 742 Evergreen Terrace
3034560817 GREEN
1032682842 XXXXXIFFIN
20231458 Spooner Street
3034560817 RED
3001

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sed 's/^\(10[0-9]\+[ \t]\+\).*$/\1XXXXXXXXXXXXX/g'
```

Example:

```
sed 's/^\(10[0-9]\+[ \t]\+\).*$/\1XXXXXXXXXXXXX/g' <<< "0120140206INPUT FILE
1032682842 MR SIMPSON
20231458 742 Evergreen Terrace
9001"
```

Comment: It works, but it removes all data that might be present after pos 12-20 of record type 10. I would like to keep this data intact.

Answer (score 0):

Using awk:

```
awk '/^10/{q=substr($0, 12); gsub(/./, "*", q); $0=substr($0, 1, 11) q}1' file
0120140206INPUT FILE
1032682842 **********
20231458 742 Evergreen Terrace
9001
```

**UPDATE:** If you want only first 10 record to be masked then use this awk:

```
awk '!done && /^10/{q=substr($0, 12);gsub(/./, "*", q);$0=substr($0, 1, 11) q;done=1}1' file
```

Comment: It works, but the masking (*) countinues to end of line for record type 10. I would like to keep the data after position 20 intact.

Comment: I didn't get your comment, please clarify. It only changes record type 10 record, rest of the data remain unchanged as you can see from output above in my answer.

Comment: After reading your comment again may be you want only first `10` record to be masked. If that is the case see updated answer.

Comment: Right and you want to change only very first type 10 record?